# How to stop a multithreaded function inside the function from running after a certain amount of time in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, algorithm, python-multithreading

I am doing an AI project, where I am using a genetic algorithm to implement the "Letters and Number", where we are given a list of numbers and the process tries to calculate the nearest value to the target by using the genetic algorithm.

For the analysis part, I want to run my program for 2 seconds and then stop and check how many generations did it ran.

The function that I am using is

```
def task2():
    Q = [100, 50, 3, 3, 10, 75]
    target = 533
    pop_list = []
    for i in range(20):
        r = random.randint(5, 1000)
        pop_list.append(r)
    start=time.time()
    PERIOD_OF_TIME = 2
    v, T = evolve_pop(Q, target,
                     max_num_iteration = 200,
                    population_size = 200 ,
                parents_portion = 0.3)
    if stop_event.is_set():
        cost = v
        print("cost: ", cost)
    print(time.time() - start)
    print(pop_list)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # We create another Thread
    action_thread = Thread(target=task2)
    # Here we start the thread and we wait 5 seconds before the code continues to execute.
    action_thread.start()
    action_thread.join(timeout=2)
    # We send a signal that the other thread should stop.
    stop_event.set()
    print("Hey there! I timed out! You can do things after me!")
```

The result is:

```
After 117 generations, the best individual has a cost of 1
After 118 generations, the best individual has a cost of 1
After 119 generations, the best individual has a cost of 1
After 120 generations, the best individual has a cost of 1
Hey there! I timed out! You can do things after me!
After 121 generations, the best individual has a cost of 1
After 122 generations, the best individual has a cost of 1
After 123 generations, the best individual has a cost of 1
After 124 generations, the best individual has a cost of 1
After 125 generations, the best individual has a cost of 1
```

Since the `evolve_pop()` is another function inside the tesk2() which still carries on even after 2 seconds.
I want to know, is there any way to exit out of evolve pop after 2 seconds/ the statement
`Hey there! I timed out! You can do things after me!` is printed.

The expected result

```
After 117 generations, the best individual has a cost of 1
After 118 generations, the best individual has a cost of 1
After 119 generations, the best individual has a cost of 1
After 120 generations, the best individual has a cost of 1
Hey there! I timed out! You can do things after me!
```

I tried using `exit()`, `quit()` and `sys.exit(0)` but non of them seems to stop the function from keep on printing.

Comment: Can you modify evolve_pop() to accept a timeout argument and have it periodically check the clock and return when the timeout time has elapsed?

Answer (score 1):

As threads share memory, usually you can interract with other threads by updating a variable. Something like:

```
running = False

def my_long_runnging_code():
    while running:
        # do something here

if __name__ == "__main__":
    thread = Thread(target=my_long_running_code)
    running = True
    thread.start()
    # we wait a bit
    time.sleep(2)
    # now we tell the thread to stop iterating
    running = False
    # it will still finish it's current computation
    thread.join()
```

Alternatively, if you don't need to share memory with your computation code, you can use python [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) instead which offers a way to interrupt your code at any time:

```
import time
import multiprocessing

def my_long_running_code():
    # doing something long

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=my_long_running_code)
    p.start()
    time.sleep(2)
    p.terminate()
```

Comment: OP is basically doing this (but more elegantly, using a threading Event). The problem is they can't interrupt the `evolve_pop` function.

Comment: If `evolve_pop` is cpu bound (which very likely is the case here) it should run in a separate process. You can easily kill it then without any risks.

Comment: I think I tried both of the methods, but somehow it just keeps on going, because the thing is it won't even check the condition ```while running``` until it is inside the ```evolve_pop```.

Answer (score 0):

With just Python's built-in bits, no, you can't interrupt a "non-cooperating" function from another thread.

There is a library on PyPI called [`stopit`](https://pypi.org/project/stopit/) that can inject an exception into another thread, which would basically do what you want.

Comment: Killing other threads in the middle of their work is usually not recommended. Especially, when they operate on shared objects, stopping the thread abruptly may leave the objects in incomplete and messed state. It's much better to use thread pools or events to notify threads. This allows them to stop at their convenience and avoid data corruption. There is a reason why e.g. JDK marked Thread.stop() as inherently unsafe.

Comment: @warownia1 That's absolutely true, and I was thinking of adding an admonition to that effect. However, the difference between `Thread.stop()` and such and `stopit` is that the latter injects an exception, which will allow any code in that thread to (try to) clean up.

Comment: They both work the same. `Thread.stop()` raises an unchecked `ThreadDetach` exception in the target thread. In python all exceptions are unchecked, so it's operation is equivalent.

Comment: @warownia1 Ah, alright. Still, a thread that has proper `with` blocks and so on would clean itself up when an exception is injected.

Comment: Well, yes, but actually no. You have control over your resources, of course. But if you are using third party libs or even a built-in python functions, they are not guaranteed to protect every tiny bit of their code from sudden exception which shouldn't be there in the first place.
You don't protect every variable/property assignment with `with` do you.

Comment: I'd expect a stdlib function or a proper third-party module to be able to gracefully handle e.g. a `MemoryError` or a `KeyboardInterrupt`, which aren't expected either.

Comment: Those two (`KeyboardInterrups` is `SIGINT` in disguise) are meant to interrup the process, not the current function. Protecting against them means "close all external resources and stop the program asap in however messed up state it is". You never expect the program to continue working after one of those. I'm talking about incomplete, half updated objects, not external resources which, I totally agree, every proper library should gracefully close.

Comment: To be exact, SIGINT causes a KeyboardInterrupt to be raised in the main thread - it's not a disguise...